# Grails rendering json to specific view

Tags: json, grails, view

in a controller I am trying to render json to a specific view.  Here is what I was doing before using json :

```
def create() {
    render(view: "/book/create", model: [bookInstance: new Book(params)])
}
```

How would I render to a specific view like above but return json instead ?  I have tried a few things like the following :

```
def create() {
    def bookInstance = new Book(params)
    render(view:"/book/create", model: [bookInstance as JSON] );
}
```

I have imported the required JSON library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is expecting a map. You can't just put anything in there without a key. Your first example has the setup:

```
render(view: "/book/create", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance as JSON])
```