# Send both JSON response and model in Grails

Tags: json, grails, datatables

I'm new to Grails and I'm stuck up with a problem. I want to know if there is a way to send both JSON and view and model through "render" in Grails.

I'm using a jQuery Datatable to display data returned from server which is read from JSON returned by the controller. I also need to display error messages on the same view in case of validation failure in form fields. But I'm able to return either only the JSON or model and view using render. I also tried sending the JSON through model itself but it didn't work.

This is my code:-

```
def hierarchyBreakInstance = new HierarchyBreak(params);
String json = "{\"sEcho\":\"1\",\"iTotalRecords\":0,\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":0,\"aaData\":[]}";

hierarchyBreakInstance.errors.reject(message(code: 'hierarchyBreak.error.division.blank'));
render(view: "hierarchyBreak", model: [hierarchyBreakInstance: hierarchyBreakInstance]);
//render json;
```

The gsp code:-

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${hierarchyBreakInstance}">
    <div class="errorMessage" role="alert">
        <g:eachError bean="${hierarchyBreakInstance}" var="error">
           <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}" > data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>
               <g:message error="${error}"/>
        </g:eachError>
    </div>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Could you please let me know if there is a way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails rendering json to specific view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713377/grails-rendering-json-to-specific-view)

Comment: i honestly hope you are not building your json like this in production code

Comment: No I'm not. I'm using this json just to show an empty datatable if a validation fails.

Comment: Also I tried adding the json to the model as mentioned in the other example but the datatable doesn't reads it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
def hierarchyBreakInstance = new HierarchyBreak(params);
String json = "{\"sEcho\":\"1\",\"iTotalRecords\":0,\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":0,\"aaData\":[]}";

hierarchyBreakInstance.errors.reject(message(code: 'hierarchyBreak.error.division.blank'));
render(view: "hierarchyBreak", model: [hierarchyBreakInstance: hierarchyBreakInstance,json:json]);
//render json;
```

Comment: I tried this already but the datatable doesn't reads the json from model.

Comment: You should use ajax to render data in data table . that will be better option.

Comment: Th request comes to the controller through ajax itself from where I need to send a json response back to the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing a request with some parameters, and need to return if was succesfull or not, and the data to fill the table with ajax.
I will do on that way, use the statuses of the HTTP to mark if it was a problem with the validation(normally we return 400 Bad Request and the message)

Example :

```
return ErrorSender.sendBadRequest("error validating field $field with value $value")
```

And the errorsender has a sendBadRequest method

```
[response: ['message': message, error: "bad_request", status: 400, cause: []], status: 400]
```

If the request was OK, you only need to respond the data with something like

```
return [response: results, status: 200]
```

In the client side you have to have one function if the request was OK to parse result, and one function if request have some validated data problem, database problem or whatever that caused that the request didn´t return a 200(in the example),there are more status codes, you can check on
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

PD: Initial validation should be done on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ricardo, but I don't need to show HTTP status codes. Rather I want to show a custom error message if the initial form field validation fails.